# A question about some exact sequence of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, exact-sequence

M. Schottenloher in his book "A mathematical introduction to conformal field theorey" in Remark 4.3 says that: For every central extension of Lie algebras $0\to \mathfrak{a}\to \mathfrak{h}\overset{\pi}{\to} \mathfrak{g}\to 0$, there is a linear map $\beta: \mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{h}$ with $\pi \circ \beta = id_{\mathfrak{g}}$ ($\beta$ is in general not a Lie algebra homomorphism). How can I define $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\beta$ is called a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)). And that exists if the short exact sequence splits. In your case then it will be a trivial extension. The explicit mapping will depend on the algebra itself but usually it should be clear once the exact sequence is defined.(It's the right inverse of the projection map $\pi$).

Note/Edit 1: A right inverse $\beta$ (as morphism in $\textbf{Set}$) always exists (but not unique unless $\mathfrak{a}=0$) as $\pi$ is surjective. But it also has to be (in this case) a morphism in $\textbf{LieAlg}$ to be a section.

For an example one can look at the (non-split) short exact sequence in $\textbf{Ab}$:
$$0 \to 2\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z/2Z} \to 0$$

Note/Edit 2 (to include Torsten helpful comments): The question asks for linear section so in fact we are looking at $\textbf{Vect}$. But every short exact sequence in $\textbf{Vect}$ splits, which can be proven by linear algebra. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363198/short-exact-sequence-of-vector-spaces-splits-always).

Comment: Dear @DonkyDang , this is not a Lie algebra homomorphism so this can't be a section. The author says that $\beta$ always exists.

Comment: @Mahtab I added something to clarify

Comment: @DonkyDang Thank you very much. Could you please tell me how we can define $\beta$? I think for $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, $\beta (X)$ is defined as $\beta (X)=Y$ where $Y\in \mathfrak{h}$ such that $\pi (Y)=X$. But $\beta$ is well-defined?

Comment: The question asks for the existence of a *linear* section. I.e. we are supposed to consider the sequence in the *category of vector spaces*. In that category, every sequence splits, and that is standard linear algebra, although it's worthwhile to see it translated to this language.

Comment: By the way "the" right inverse of a surjective map is usually not unique. In fact, except in trivial cases, even for the linear sections one has choices here (it's basically choosing bases).

Comment: @Mahtab yes it should be well defined by using surjectivity of $\pi$ and the underlying vector space structure of Lie algebras.

Comment: @DonkyDang I got it. Thank you very much for your help.